# How many numbers with a digit sum N are smaller than a given number?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, for N=23, how many numbers smaller than 1 000 000 000 000 are there with the sum of decimal digits equal to N?

The smallest such number is 599, as 5+9+9=23 and there exist no smaller ones. Next are 689, 698, 779, 788, 797, 869, ...

But how many are there exactly below a given large number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on @Arthur's answer, for larger $N$, the calculation has to take care of the cases where up to $\lfloor N/10\rfloor$ digit buckets contain at least $10$ points. The example $N=23$ means $\lfloor N/10\rfloor = 2$, hence just two extra adjustment terms.

Generally there can be more adjustment terms, which can be calculated by [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement).

Let $S$ be the set of ways to put $N$ points into $12$ digit buckets, without restrictions.

Let $A_i \subset S$ be the set of ways that the $i$-th digit bucket contains at least $10$ points, for $i=0,1,2,\ldots, 11$. Then $\overline {A_i}$ is the set where the $i$-th digit contains less than $10$ points.

The required sum is the intersection when all $12$ digits contain less than $10$ points:

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcap_{i=0}^{11}\overline{A_i}\right|
&= \left| S\right| - \sum_{i=0}^{11} \left|A_i\right| + \sum_{0\le i<j\le11} \left|A_i\cap A_j\right| - \cdots + (-1)^{12}\left|A_0\cap A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_{11}\right|\\
&= \binom{11+N}{11} - \sum_{i=0}^{11} \binom{11 + (N - 10)}{11} + \sum_{0\le i<j\le11} \binom{11+(N-20)}{11} - \cdots + \binom{11+(N-120)}{11}\\
&= \binom{11+N}{11} - \binom{12}{1}\binom{11 + (N - 10)}{11} + \binom{12}{2} \binom{11+(N-20)}{11} - \cdots + \binom{11+(N-120)}{11}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor N/10\rfloor}(-1)^k \binom{12}{k} \binom{11 + N - 10k}{11}
\end{align*}$$

for $N$ up to $108$.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to think of it like this: We have $23$ "digit points", and we would like to distribute them among the 12 available digits, and count the number of ways that this can be done (we are lucky that the bound we're given is a power of $10$, that does make things a lot easier).

Now, without any restrictions, this is a typical stars-and-bars problem. Then the answer is $\binom{11 + 23}{23}$. However, this includes, for instance, the possibility of putting all 23 into the units digit. This is illegal, so we need to correct our count.

So, how many of the distributions from the previous paragraph are illegal? Well, an illegal distribution is any distribution where one or more digits have $10$ or more points assigned to them. So we count how many there are of those, and subtract them. Pick one of the ten digits, assign $10$ points to it, then assign the remaining $13$ points freely. How many ways can that be done? It can be done in $12\cdot \binom{11 + 13}{13}$ ways. So that's how many illegal distributions we have.

Or not. We have double counted a couple of the illegal distributions. For instance, picking the first digit and placing $10$ points there, then in the free placing putting all the remaining points into the second digit has been counted as separate from picking the second digit and placing $10$ points there, then in the free placing putting $10$ points in the first digit and three points in the second. And this is not the only one.

In fact, any placement of points that has two digits with $10$ or more points has been counted as illegal *twice*. So we have to take this into account when we find the total number of illegal placements. How many of these are there? Well, there are $\binom{12}2$ ways to choose the two digits and place $10$ points in each, then there are $\binom{11+3}{3}$ ways to place the remaining three points.

All in all, there are $12\cdot \binom{11+13}{13} - \binom{12}{2}\cdot\binom{11 + 3}{3}$ illegal point distributions. So we subtract those from the $\binom{11 + 23}{23}$ total, and we have our answer.